# Can't deploy cloud functions after deleting old files from artifacts

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Angular website, hosted on Firebase was getting charged for cloud storage since the beginning of this year, because of `us.artifacts.<project-id>` bucket.

Yesterday, I checked the storage usage and found ~800MB+ data stored on cloud storage. The default bucket is empty and I've stored nothing on it. So all this 800MB storage is used by function builds.

I've 2 Node 10 functions (and 2 node 8 functions) in the project. Node 8 functions are deprecated but it's deployed last year. It won't use `us.artifacts` bucket.

**Following [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63888296/2427065), and a comment,**

> The dates of the files correspond to the dates of deployment. It should not be hard to figure out which ones are old enough to delete. – Doug Stevenson Sep 15 '20 at 3:56

**I deployed both functions yesterday and deleted the files dated before from the bucket. Since then, I'm not able to deploy both functions.**

#### Here's what I've tried so far.

1. Waited for 8-10 hours and tried re deploying - failed.
2. Removed both functions from firebase functions dashboard and deployed again - failed.
3. Removed both functions from firebase dashboard, verified it doesn't exist on Google Cloud functions list, deleted both `us.artifacts<project-id>` and `gcf-sources-<id>` buckets from Google cloud. Then deployed the functions as new functions - failed.
4. Done everything on step 3, except deployment, then renamed both functions and tried deploying again - failed.
5. Rerun a previous, successful workflow on CircleCI from start - failed.

#### This is the deployment log

> functions: Finished running predeploy script. functions: ensuring
>
> required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... functions:
>
> ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
>
> functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
>
> functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
>
> functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... functions:
>
> packaged functions (39.63 KB) for uploading functions: functions
>
> folder uploaded successfully functions: current functions in project:
>
> sendEnquiryMessage(us-central1), ssr(us-central1) functions: uploading
>
> functions in project: api(us-central1) functions: creating Node.js 10
>
> function api(us-central1)... functions[api(us-central1)]: Deployment
> error. Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a
> bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your
> function logs to see the error cause:
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
> Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging.
> Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting
> for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
> api

The error on firebase console says failed to load user code.

[image]

I use CircleCI for CI/CD and even rerunning a previous successful workflow fails throwing this error.

**Here's a screenshot from CircleCI rerunning previous workflow**

[image]

Note: I'm using TypeScript for Cloud functions.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is resolved. Here's the steps I followed.

1. Changed Node version from 10 to 12 in functions/package.json
2. Deleted function from firebase dashboard (even if deploy failed, you can see the name in the dashboard).
3. Deleted `us.artifacts.<project-id>` and `gcf-sources-<id>` buckets from Storage.
4. Deployed again.

**Function has been deployed successfully after the node version change.**

Comment: Step 2. was sufficient for me (because i accidently did 3.)