# Google Cloud Functions deploy - NoSuchKey failure (us.artifacts. sha256 image) after creating delete rules

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

After realizing I was being charged for storage as a result of Google Cloud Functions deployments, I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937542/can-i-delete-container-images-from-google-cloud-storage-artifacts-bucket) and created a 3-day deletion rule for my us.artifacts.{myproject}.appspot.com folder. Now I am trying to deploy an existing function and am getting the below. How can I resolve this? Should I delete the whole image folder?

```
[0mfailed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [us.gcr.io/myproject/gcf/us-central1/3a36a5e8-92b5-426e-b230-ba19ffc92ba8:MYFUNCTION_version-64: 
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/us.artifacts.myproject.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:{some long string}?access_token=REDACTED:
unsupported status code 404; body: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: us.artifacts.myproject.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:{some long string}</Details></Error>]
```

Edit 1: My deploy command (which has been previously working for months):

`gcloud functions deploy MYFUNCTIONNAME --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/MYPROJECT/repos/MYREPO --trigger-http --runtime nodejs10 --allow-unauthenticated`

**Update October 2023**: We deployed a brand new v1 Cloud Function this week, and when trying to update it for the first time ran into this bug again. The current best solution seems to be to [migrate from Container Registry to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo), as there seems to be a bug where even deleting lifecycle rules and the container bucket still results in the build error.

Comment: 1) Not all answer on Stackover are good solutions. 2) Delete your rule. 3) Do not delete anything trying to fix this. 4) Redeploy your Cloud Functions app which will recreate the artifacts.

Comment: @JohnHanley what do you mean redeploy my cloud functions app? I've tried deploying numerous times via gcloud command line as well as manually in the UI and keep getting the same failure

Comment: Include your deployment command and configuration in your question. For example are you deploying to the same tag you broke? Details matter when debugging problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you, I have edited the question to include my deploy command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I delete container images from Google Cloud Storage artifacts bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937542/can-i-delete-container-images-from-google-cloud-storage-artifacts-bucket)

Comment: @policenauts did you ever get to the bottom of this? Or was it all good once you renamed (Edit 3)? 
We are seeing the same issue with 2 CF deployments. We applied the deletion rule to the bucket ~ 1 year ago, and its only started to affect some of our CF instances as well.

Comment: @CurtisMenmuir it's been a while, but in our case we haven't run into this bug again. But I believe the accepted answer is best where you can just delete the bucket which shouldn't affect the function in production, and then at that point redeploy without issue.

Comment: @CurtisMenmuir I spoke too soon, I just tried to update a v1 Cloud Function and am also hitting this again now. I tried deleting the us.artifacts bucket folder entirely, but it's still giving me the error (and recreating the empty folder on each deploy attempt). I have tried reading and following some of the documentation for the migration to Artifact Registry, and am hitting a wall. Were you able to solve this without re-deploying a new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is recommended in the answer of the [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942115/11529321), it is better delete the whole bucket, this action will destroy all elements and configurations related to this bucket, avoiding issues between Functions, Storage & Container Registry, if you delete only the containers some configurations will be remained affecting further deploys.

Comment: I will leave this as the accepted answer as it worked previously, but as of Oct 2023 we are facing a bug with v1 Cloud Functions where even deleting the bucket does not resolve this. We ultimately had to migrate from Container Registry to Artifact Registry in order for functions to deploy successfully again.