# How to change the lcoation of firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Hello everyone while checking my costs for my firebase project, I detect that I have high cost caused by  appspot . My GCP- is located at eur3 (europe-west). But my firebase Storage is Multi-Regional. So my question is can I change the location for firbebase Storage ? My question is not about us.artficats only about if it's makes sense to change location of firebase storage if so then how ?
[image]

Also as you can see that us.artifacts....appspot.com takes HUGE Bandwidth. The Problem should be fixed in Firebase CLI 9.14 but mine is 9.23.1. So I have no idea what caused this problem.Please leave also a solution(if you know a fix )down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage for Firebase stores your files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, making them accessible through both Firebase and Google Cloud. Cloud Storage location is set on a bucket and you can create different buckets in different locations. You can [change the storage class of the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/changing-default-storage-class) but changing the location for the bucket is not supported currently. So if you want you can create another bucket with the preferred location. You can follow this guide on [how to move and rename the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets).

Now about the huge bandwidth taken by the us.artifacts....appspot.com bucket, I would suggest you setting up the Life Cycle Management Policy on the bucket as mentioned in [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690248).

Comment: hey thanks for answering but there kigjt be a problem. i cannot find a bucket named us.artifacts.,, in my storage browser. Also for zhe bucket i deleted the old bucket and create a new one with prefered location. is the way i did fine? And last question did i understand it correctly that the orange on is for the saving the files and so on which i saved , currently i save videos. because i have detect now that i have a sended bandwidth of 19.8 gb just in one day caused by the orange one. why is that so huge?

Comment: edit I found the artifacts and add rule like the post above. But please keep a look on the other questions.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found the artifacts bucket and added the Life Cycle Management rule. For the second question, yes it is fine to delete the old bucket and create a new one in your preferred location as long as you don't need the data that was there in the old bucket. For the third question, I didn't understand the complete question, but the orange one is project-id.appspot.com, which is the default bucket that is created when you create an App Engine App as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-cloud-storage#default_bucket).