# High Surge usage on Storage and bandwidth when deploying Cloud / Firebase Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a 3.8gb usage on my `Google Cloud Storage` , and I don't know why , I deleted all my buckets from console (Cloud Storage) but still it has data in it , later on I dinged deeper and fond the following page it has loads of data including `Cloud Functions` and strange buckets , any idea how to clean my app on `Google Cloud` for those potential junk data that keeps on growing for some reason ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are the artifacts for your services. Are your running anything in App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, etc?

Comment: I run cloud functions in testing..... but how are cloud functions related to storage and if they are , 3.8gb ? is too much..  to me it looks like junk data snowballing somewhere, but I don't want to delete the artifacts I don't want to crash demo production

Comment: My advice, do not delete artifacts unless you know exactly what you are doing. That will crash your services. You blacked out the names, so I cannot see what you have but the one that starts with **gcf-sources** is your Cloud Function source code. Google documents what each bucket is for, research before doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **3.81 GB** usage on your `Google Cloud Storage` shown in your `Firebase` dashboard is normal because the `Cloud Functions` is now integrating the use of `Cloud Build` in the [deployment process](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment).

> Deployments work by uploading an archive containing your function's source code to a Cloud Storage bucket. Once the source code has been uploaded, Cloud Build automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to either Artifact Registry or Container Registry. Cloud Functions uses that image to create the container that executes your function.

With this pipeline, the **Artifacts buckets** are created automatically in order to store the containerized functions.

As you can see on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942115/10190802), it is safe to delete the images stored in your buckets if you desire. This can be achieved by setting [lifecycle deletion rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles) on the **artifacts buckets** to **mitigate additional costs** generated by an excess of build images.

**Note:** As mentioned by @JohnHanley, the bucket that starts with **gcf-sources** is your Cloud Functions source code. If you delete it, you will not be able to see your source code in the **source tab** in your functions.

Sample screenshot if the source code in your Functions is deleted in the bucket:
[image]